# Strange Problem With GridView, an ObjectDataSource and Two RadioButtons in a Group

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm facing a very strange problem with a GridView, an ObjectDataSource and two RadioButtons in a group. After several weeks looking at live code and a simplified example I can't find a solution. I think it may be a bug in ASP.Net so was wondering if anyone had encountered anything similar? Any comments or suggestions gratefully received - I've tried everything I can think of.

EnableViewState is set to false for the GridView and this causes the Select and Count methods to be called twice - once so that the GridView can work out what its state was before postback and once so that it can get the new data to be displayed. (In this case the GridView does not carry out CRUD operations so calling Select and Count methods twice is unwanted behavior but I can't find any way of stopping it.)

The values of controls on the page are passed to the ObjectDataSource using select parameters (these are used to select the data to be displayed).

When it does the second call to count and select, all values are always correct. When it does the first call, however, parameters containing the contents of text boxes are always correct but parameters for RadioButtons which are part of a group are wrong. This causes an incorrect count to be returned which messes up paging. The problem only seems to affect RadioButtons which are in a group - when a group is not specified they work correctly.

From the simplified example, here are the text boxes, the button that causes the postback and the radio buttons:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" 
              Width="160px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch2" runat="server" 
             Width="160px" Height="23px"></asp:TextBox>
&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="cmdGo" runat="server" Width="75px" Height="24px" Text="Find!" 
            EnableViewState="true"></asp:Button>
&nbsp;

<div class="OptionGroupSpacer">-</div>
    <div class="OptionGroup">
        <asp:RadioButton ID="Option1" runat="server" Text="Option1" 
                         GroupName="Group1" EnableViewState="true" />
        <asp:RadioButton ID="Option2" runat="server" GroupName="Group1"
                         Text="Option2" EnableViewState="true" /></div>
```

And the ObjectdataSource with select parameters:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="EntriesDataSource" runat="server" 
                      TypeName="Dictionary.clsEntryDAL"
                      SortParameterName="SortExpression" 
                      SelectMethod="SelectEntries" EnablePaging="True"
                      SelectCountMethod="Count" EnableViewState="true"  >
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch" Name="txtSearch" 
                              PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="txtSearch2" Name="txtSearch2" 
                              PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Option1" Name="Option1" 
                              PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="Option2" Name="Option2" 
                              PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

And the GridView (which contains a Rating control from the ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit.)

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdEntriesNew" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" CellPadding="4"
  DataSourceID="EntriesDataSource" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Visible="true" CssClass="Entries"
  BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false" EnableViewState="false">
  <RowStyle CssClass="Row" />
  <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="AlternatingRow" />
  <Columns>
  <asp:BoundField DataField="NewLayout" DataFormatString="{0}" HtmlEncode="false" Visible="true" />
    <asp:TemplateField ControlStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-Width="52px" ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
           <ContentTemplate>
            <ajaxToolkit:Rating runat="server" ID="DynamicRating1" CurrentRating='<%# Bind("Votes") %>'
              MaxRating="3" CssClass="ratingStar" StarCssClass="ratingItem" WaitingStarCssClass="Saved"
              FilledStarCssClass="Filled" EmptyStarCssClass="Empty" AutoPostBack="False" Width="42px"
              Enabled="False" ReadOnly="True" Tag='<%# Bind("ID") %>' BorderStyle="None" ToolTip="Please vote"
              BorderWidth="3px" EnableViewState="true">
            </ajaxToolkit:Rating>
          </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="EditLink" DataFormatString="{0}" HtmlEncode="false" Visible="true" ItemStyle-Width="30px">
<ItemStyle Width="30px"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This causes the count and select methods

```
Public Function count(ByVal txtSearch As String, _
                      ByVal txtSearch2 As String, _
                      ByVal Option1 As Boolean, _
                      ByVal Option2 As Boolean, _
                      ByVal CurrentUserID As Integer) As Integer
```

...

and

```
Public Function SelectEntries(ByVal txtSearch As String, _
                              ByVal txtSearch2 As String, _
                              ByVal Option1 As Boolean, _
                              ByVal Option2 As Boolean, _
                              ByVal maximumRows As Integer, _
                              ByVal startRowIndex As Integer, _
                              ByVal SortExpression As String, _
                              ByVal CurrentUserID As Integer) As IList(Of clsEntryShort)
```

...

to be called once when the first search is done and twice for each subsequent search.

In subsequent searches, the first time the count and select methods are called the txtSearch and txtSearch2 string values read from text boxes are always correct but the Option1 and Option2 boolean values read from the RadioButtons are wrong.

The problem is only present with the RadioButtons when they're in a group - not when they're not in a group. Text boxes always work perfectly.

The GridView contains ASP.Net AJAX controls which are databound to the same data as the GridView - if these controls are not present the Select and Count methods are not called twice.

The problem is only apparent when the GridView's EnableViewState is set to false (EnableViewState cannot simply be set to true in this application because this causes a very large ViewState to be generated which causes performance problems).

The problem also seems to be present with DropDownList controls but I haven't looked at them in so much detail.

Any thoughts gratefully received!

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - I should have clarified that the GridView contains AJAX controls which are bound to the same data as the DataGrid. If the AJAX controls are absent from the GridView the Select and Count methods are not called twice - have updated the posting.

Comment: Added source for the GridView above following suggestion from a friend. Many thanks.